# disparadores o Procedimiento almacenado mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, trigger

Estoy realizando un proyecto de naves industriales y bodegas pero tengo una duda al momento de realizar el registro de contratos. Cuando registro un contrato se ocupa una bodega que esta identificada por su id. El problema viene cuando registro 2 contratos en una bodega al mismo tiempo. quiero evitar esto y me sugirieron usar o disparadores o procedimientos almacenados. Quisiera saber su opinión y si me pueden dar una idea de como seria.

esta es la tabla de contratos

```
create table Contratos (
ID_BN int not null,
ID_Empresa int not null,
ID_Contrato int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
ID_Empleado int not null,
Fecha_Contrato date not null,
Estatus_C varchar (15) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_Contrato));
```

y esta la de bodegas y naves

```
create table Bodenave (
ID_BN int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
Nombre_BN varchar(30) not null,
Tipo varchar (30) not null,
Localizacion varchar (50) not null,
Precio_renta decimal (7,2) not null,
Estatus_BN varchar (15) not null,
Metros_ancho decimal (4,2) not null,
Metros_largo decimal (4,2) not null,
Oficinas varchar (30) not null,
PRIMARY KEY (ID_BN));
```

Agradecería su ayuda

Comment: StackOverflow no es un sitio donde podamos pedir _opiniones_, las discusiones de este tipo no están permitidas en el sistema. Sugiero que edites tu pregunta y te refieras a un problema concreto, de otra forma la comunidad terminará cerrándola. Para más información, te invito a leer [ask]. Un saludo.